# How to interrupt spritecollide?

Tags: python, pygame

Drive a car through an area with houses. If the car hit a house, the car stops and there is supposed to be ONE printed message. Since the car remains in contact with the house for longer - even if I then drive backwards - there are a number of messages instead of just ONE. How can I make there only one message?

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide( auto, land, False)   
for hit in hits:        
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(auto, land, False):     
        print("hit ")
```

Comment: i am a beginner, not so clever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the hits from the previous frame in a list, just print a message if the hit wasn't there in the previous frame:

```py
old_hits = []

# application loop
while True:
    # [...]
    
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide( auto, land, False)   
    for hit in hits:        
        if hit not in old_hits:     
            print("hit ")
    old_hits = hits
```